# Is it possible to make Kendo Autocomplete list of Item a Link?

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I have the following code for Autocomplete, It loads data and filter the result.

Is it possible to make Kendo Autocomplete list items a link?  I am looking when items in the list selected or when submit button clicked i want navigate to a page as ...Product/Details/id. I couldn't find a way pass id with a form.

I need your help if anyone know if kendo have built in functionality to make them a link or If this can be accomplish this using JavaScript?

I tried to research a lot couldn't find anything.

```
 <form id="Search" asp-action="Details" asp-controller="Product" method="post">
     @(Html.Kendo().AutoComplete()
                       .Name("Product")
                       .DataTextField("ProductName")                       
                       .Filter("contains")                  
                       .Template("#= ID# - #= ProductName #")                    
                       .DataSource(source =>
                        {
                        source
                            .Read(read =>
                            {
                            read.Action("Search", "Product")
                            .Data("onAdditionalData");
                            })
                        .ServerFiltering(false);
                       })
                )
 <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can do like this

```
.Template("<a href=" + Url.Action("Details", "Product") + "?Id=#= ID#>#= ProductName #</a>")
```

Comment: I had it make it work but you make it more pretty, but do you know if i can search with multiple field DataText?

Comment: Hi if you have any idea :) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61494044/how-can-i-show-and-hide-panel-based-on-li-data-id

Comment: How can i navigate to the actionLink url when enter key pressed